# How can I get a cohomology of hypersurfaces by using their equation?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, projective-geometry

While studying about complex projective hypersurfaces, I attempts to find a cohomology of this hypersurface :
$$X_n=\{(x_0:x_1:x_2:x_3) \in \mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^3~|~x_0^n+x_1^n+x_2^n+x_3^n=0\}$$

I think that its cohomology only depend on $n$ but I can't prove it.
Is there any way to calculate its cohomology by using its equation?

Comment: What else apart from $n$ could it possibly depend on?

Comment: One way to «compute the cohomology by using the equation» is to use the theorem of Grothendieck+Hartshorne stating that the usual de Rham cohomology of a smooth complex projective variety is isomorphic to its algebraic de Rham cohomology, which is the hypercohomology of the complex of sheaves of Kähler differential forms on the variety. (Part of) the content of this theorem is a very precise way in which the "topological" cohomolgy can be obtained from the equations.

Comment: @Mariano: it *could* depend on the specific equation. For a real  plane smooth curve $X\subset \mathbb P^2_\mathbb R$ for example, even $H^0(X,\mathbb Z)$ is not determined by the degree $n$ of $X$.

Comment: But this is a specific equation depending only on $n$ cutting a specific variety in $P^3_\mathbb C$ :-)

Comment: @Mariano: Sorry, I misunderstood your comment. What I meant was that it is not evident that the topology only depends on $n$, independently of the form of the equation. Although this last statement is actually true over $\mathbb C$, as explained by Qiaochu in his answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2014/06/16/hypersurfaces-4-manifolds-and-characteristic-classes/). It's true in general that the cohomology of a smooth hypersurface of degree $n$ in $\mathbb{CP}^d$ only depends on $d$ and $n$.